# Token not returning from samsung smart tv remote control API

Tags: samsung-mobile, samsung-smart-tv, remote-control, samsung-mobile-sdk

I want to develop a Remote control for iOS devices. For that, I am using the below API to get a token from Samsung TV but it's not returning me Token which I can use for further Remote control commands.
ws://192.168.29.53:8001/api/v2/channels/samsung.remote.control?name=U2Ftc3VuZ1JlbW90ZUFwcA==

I am able to get connected TV information by iOS SDK. My TV and app are connected to the same network connection.

The above API gives me the response as below:

> {
> "event": "ms.channel.connect",
> "data": {
> "id": "9bcfee40-66a0-11ee-885d-ed03655c04c0",
> "clients": [
> {
> "id": "9bcfee40-66a0-11ee-885d-ed03655c04c0",
> "connectTime": 1696855048996,
> "attributes": {
> "name": "U2Ftc3VuZ1JlbW90ZUFwcA=="
> },
> "deviceName": "U2Ftc3VuZ1JlbW90ZUFwcA==",
> "isHost": false
> }
> ]
> }
> }

Can anyone help me out by getting a token from a connected socket?

I tried both port 8002 and 8001 but I am getting device info with only 8001 and with ws://

Answer (score 0):

Create the token on their website and then include the token in your request. Try with this: [https://developer.smartthings.com/docs/advanced/authorization-and-permissions#:~:text=To%20generate%20a%20Personal%20Access,%22Personal%20Access%20Tokens%22%20page](https://developer.smartthings.com/docs/advanced/authorization-and-permissions#:%7E:text=To%20generate%20a%20Personal%20Access,%22Personal%20Access%20Tokens%22%20page). I don't know if you're doing it on Swift (you used the Swift tag) but would be nice if you included some extra code to see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I am getting connected device information with my iOS app. First I discovered services which are connected to the same network and among them I selected my TV for which I need to send commands for Remote control. I am requesting TV through the mentioned API and even after allowing it from TV it's not returning me a token in response. I wonder even if successfully socket establishment It's not returning the token.

Answer (score 0):

First check, is Your device supports token Auth Support or not by using this URL.

```
curl --location 'http://YourIP:8001/api/v2/'
```

Then if it give you true then use this provided webSocket URL,

```
wss://YourIP:8002/api/v2/channels/samsung.remote.control?name="encodedAppName"
```

And if you got false then use this webSocket URL,

```
ws://YourIP:8001/api/v2/channels/samsung.remote.control?name="encodedAppName"
```

as the response of this webSocket, you will get a authToken which you need to store for future like for fire the commands by using this webSocket URL.

```
wss://YourIP:8002/api/v2/channels/samsung.remote.control?name="encodedAppName"&token="generatedAuthToken"
```